# SQL Server : get name for each id in a row from another table (ASP.net)

Tags: asp.net, sql, join, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am developing a site in VS2010 using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express and C#

My tables are like:

**Table 1**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XeSr.png]

I want to write a query that will select all rows from table 1 but instead of showing `choice1` or (2..3)'s ID, it will grab their name from table 2

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get data from this two table by join the same table three time.

```
       SELECT table2.name AS choice1name, table2_1.name AS choice2name, table2_2.name AS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                choice3name
       FROM  table1 INNER JOIN
             table2 ON table1.choice1 = table2.id INNER JOIN
             table2 AS table2_1 ON table1.choice2 = table2_1.id INNER JOIN
             table2 AS table2_2 ON table1.choice3 = table2_2.id
```

Comment: I am not joining table1's id with table2's id
but `table1.choice1 to table2.id`
then same way...`table1.choice2 to table2.id`
and.. `table1.choice3 to table2.id`

so its a kind of many-to-one relation

Comment: What u want. Do u want to show name in place of choice1, choice2 and choice3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need an inner joins. I had the same situation few weeks ago and i was referred to the link I am giving you.
Look here to find out which one will work for you. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347703/how-to-get-referenced-values-from-another-table) or this one
[Inner joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)