# How to create an sql command that has SELECT statements from 2 different tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to create an sql command that has SELECT statements from 2 different tables? For example,

```
select ID from EMP_details, select job_id from Jobs_details
```

So how can i possibly merge both into one

Comment: Or unions. What are the expected results?

Comment: You can do a lot of things with two tables

Answer (score 3):

Selecting from two or more tables When rows in them tables has some sort of relation so you want to extract the corresponding row you would use a JOIN something like this ....
**JOIN**

```
SELECT EMP.ID, JD.job_id
FROM EMP_details EMP  INNER JOIN jobs_details JD 
ON EMP.CommonColumn = JD.CommonColumn
```

**Results From Two SELECTS**
When you have two SELECT statements and just want to  get the results returned from them queries into one row you can do something like this ...

```
SELECT X.A , Y.B
FROM (select ID AS A from EMP_details) X, (select job_id AS B from Jobs_details) Y
```

Comment: ----> how can use 2 join statements together for a sql command. Should i add any comma between the statements??

Comment: +1 for the detailed syntax including the INNER JOIN and table aliases.

Comment: @fluuufffy Have a look here I explained in a bit more detail in one of my previous answers to an another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347703/how-to-get-referenced-values-from-another-table/19349215#19349215

Answer (score 1):

This is known as a JOIN in SQL. Your query might look like this:

```
SELECT EMP_details.ID,
       EMP_details.Name,
       Job_details.RefNumber
FROM   EMP_details,
       Jobs_details
WHERE  EMP_details.ID = Jobs_details.job_id;
```

Comment: ---> how can use 2 join statements together for a sql command. Should i add any comma between the statements??

Comment: You can separate two statements within a transaction with semi-colon, but I think your question is about creating a query across two or more tables using the relationships that exist between the tables. If this is the case, you will need one statement that joins across all of the tables that contain the columns that you need to answer your query.

Answer (score 1):

Having a column in both tables by which you can match the rows from the first table to the second one, like for example the job_id in Jobs_details matches job_id in Emp_details, you could do:

```
SELECT e.ID,j.job_id
FROM EMP_details e
INNER JOIN jobs_details j ON e.job_id = j.job_id
```

For more information on JOIN's [see the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx).

Comment: ---> how can use 2 join statements together for a sql command. Should i add any comma between the statements??

Comment: That doesn't make much sense for your question. If you have a column that you can join by, this is sufficient to get the related information from two tables. But if you want to join multiple tables, you just add an extra inner join and add the matching column from a third table to one of the columns in the first two.

Comment: Yes it doesn't make any sense to my question, but i was just asking for my own understanding.

Comment: Ah. Then you can see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19756241/1385896) i gave earlier today that has multiple joins, to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try

```
SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM EMP_details UNION ALL SELECT id FROM Jobs_details) as temp_table;
```

Thanks,